# can use the method of pymongo to obtain securities occupation funds and securities quantity？

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongodb data like below:

```
     code    date      num  price  money
0      2  2015-11-15   10    3.8  -38.0
1      2  2015-11-17  -10    3.7   37.0
2      2  2015-11-20   20    3.5  -70.0
3      2  2016-04-01   10    3.2  -32.0
4      2  2016-04-02  -30    3.6  108.0
5      2  2016-04-03   50    3.4 -170.0
6      2  2016-11-01  -40    3.5  140.0
7      3  2015-02-01   25    7.0 -175.0
8      3  2015-05-01   35    7.5 -262.5
9      3  2016-03-01  -15    8.0  120.0
10     5  2015-11-20   50    5.0 -250.0
11     5  2016-06-01  -50    5.5  275.0
12     6  2015-02-01   35   11.5 -402.5
```

### I want to get the number of securities held and the funds currently occupied by the securities
If I take out the data, I can get the result I want in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'code': [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,5,5,6],
        'date': ['2015-11-15','2015-11-17','2015-11-20','2016-04-01','2016-04-02','2016-04-03','2016-11-01','2015-02-01','2015-05-01','2016-03-01','2015-11-20','2016-06-01','2015-02-01'],
        'num' : [10,-10, 20, 10, -30,50, -40, 25, 35, -15, 50, -50, 35],
        'price': [3.8,3.7,3.5,3.2, 3.6,3.4, 3.5, 7, 7.5,  8, 5,  5.5, 11.5],
        'money': [-38,37,-70,-32, 108,-170, 140,-175,-262.5,120,-250, 275,-402.5]
        })


print(df,"\n------------------------------------------\n")
df['hold'] = df.groupby(['code'])['num'].cumsum()
df['type'] = np.where(df['hold'] > 0, 'B', 'S')
df['total']=df['total1']= df.groupby(['code'])['money'].cumsum()

def FiFo(dfg):
  if dfg[dfg['hold'] == 0]['hold'].count():
    subT = dfg[dfg['hold'] == 0]['total1'].iloc[-1]
    dfg['total'] = np.where(dfg['hold'] > 0, dfg['total']-subT, dfg['total'])
  return dfg
dfR = df.groupby(['code'], as_index=False)\
    .apply(FiFo) \
    .drop(['type', 'total1'], axis=1) \
    .reset_index(drop=True)

df1=dfR.groupby(['code']).tail(1)
print(df1,"\n------------------------------------------\n")
```

```
out
     code     date    num  price  money  *hold*  *total*
6      2  2016-11-01  -40    3.5  140.0    *10*  *-30.0*
9      3  2016-03-01  -15    8.0  120.0    *45* *-317.5*
11     5  2016-06-01  -50    5.5  275.0     *0*   *25.0*
12     6  2015-02-01   35   11.5 -402.5    *35* *-402.5*
```

### If use the mongodb method (such as aggregate, or other), how can i directly obtain the same result as above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer on this website below
https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/help-writing-aggregation-query-using-pymongo-instead-of-pandas/6290/13

```
pipeline = [
  {
       '$sort': { 'code': 1, 'date': 1 }
   },
  { 
      '$group': { 
          '_id': '$code', 
          'num': { '$last': '$num' }, 'price': { '$last': '$price' }, 'money': { '$last': '$money' }, 
          'code_data': { '$push': { 'n': "$num", 'm': "$money" } } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      '$addFields': { 
          'result': { 
               '$reduce': { 
                   'input': '$code_data', 
                   'initialValue': { 'hold': 0, 'sum_m': 0, 'total': 0 }, 
                   'in': { 
                       '$let': {
                           'vars': { 
                               'hold_': { '$add': [ '$$this.n', '$$value.hold' ] },  
                               'sum_m_': { '$add': [ '$$this.m',  '$$value.sum_m' ] }
                            },
                            'in': { 
                                '$cond': [ { '$eq': [ '$$hold_', 0 ] },  
                                           { 'hold': '$$hold_', 'sum_m': 0, 'total': '$$sum_m_' },
                                           { 'hold': '$$hold_', 'sum_m': '$$sum_m_', 'total': '$$sum_m_' }
                                         ] 
                            }
                        }
                    }
               } 
           }
      } 
  },
  { 
      '$addFields': { 'code': '$_id',  'hold': '$result.hold', 'total': '$result.total' } 
  },
  { 
      '$project': { 'code_data': 0, 'result': 0, '_id': 0 } 
  },
  { 
      '$sort': { 'code': 1 } 
  }
]
```